# Will RPC on App Engine localize to a single instance?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm using RPC to fetch multiple URLs asynchronously. I'm using a global variable to track completion and notice that the contents of that global have radically different contents before and after the RPC calls complete.

Feels like I'm missing something obvious... Is it possible for the rpc.wait() to result in the app context being loaded on a new instance when the callbacks are made?

Here's the basic pattern...

```
aggregated_results = {}

def aggregateData(sid):
    # local variable tracking results
    aggregated_results[sid] = []

    # create a bunch of asynchronous url fetches to get all of the route data
    rpcs = []
    for r in routes:
        rpc = urlfetch.create_rpc()
        rpc.callback = create_callback(rpc,sid)
        urlfetch.make_fetch_call(rpc, url)
        rpcs.append(rpc)

    # all of the schedule URLs have been fetched. now wait for them to finish
    for rpc in rpcs:
        rpc.wait()

    # look at results
    try:
        if len(aggregated_results[sid]) == 0:
            logging.debug("We couldn't find results for transaction")
    except KeyError as e:
        logging.error('aggregation error: %s' % e.message)
        logging.debug(aggregated_results)

    return aggregated_results[sid]


def magic_callback(rpc, sid):

    # do some work to parse the result
    # of the urlfetch call...
    #  <hidden>
    #

    try:
        if len(aggregated_results[sid]) == 0:
            aggregated_results[sid] = [stop]
        else:
            done = False
            for i, s in enumerate(aggregated_results[sid]):
                if stop.time <= s.time:
                        aggregated_results[sid].insert(i,stop)
                        done = True
                        break
            if not done:
                aggregated_results[sid].append(stop)
     except KeyError as e:
        logging.error('aggregation error: %s' % e.message)
```

The KeyError is thrown both inside the callback as well as the end of processing all of the results. Neither of those should happen.

When I print out the contents of the dictionary, the sid is in fact gone, but there are other entries for other requests that are being processed. In some cases, more entries than I see when the respective request starts.

This pattern is called on a web request handler. Not in the background.

It's as if, the callbacks occur on a difference instance.

The sid key in this case is a combination of strings that includes a time string and I'm confident it is unique.

Comment: This entire set of code will only be run on a single instance.  I assume you are running this from a task and not a front facing request ?

Comment: You appear to be missing code, what is the scope of `aggregated_results` I assume aggregated_results is supposed to be a closure, but I can't see how it is being defined or it's scope.

Comment: I've updated the code example to be more accurate. This code is run on a web request handler.